# sshpass installed but not working

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

Hi i am working on distributed environment and installing hadoop but when i am doing that i am getting error

```
fatal: [server2.impetus.co.in] => to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program
```

It says to install sshpass so i did

```
[root@server2 mapr]# yum install sshpass
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Package sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

It says it is already installed but when i run sshpass

```
[root@server2 mapr]# sshpass
bash: sshpass: command not found
```

When i look further i found it is working as **sshpass1**

Why it is running like this and how can i run sshpass command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked i just created a softlink of sshpass1

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s sshpass1 sshpass
```